# Grant EXECUTE on all STABLE or IMMUTABLE functions to a postgres role by default

Tags: postgresql, roles, postgresql-9.6

I want to create a read-only postgres role, and I want the role to be able to use functions that don't modify the database, including functions I might create in the future. Since they don't modify the database (and satisfy the other requirements), I've been marking these functions as STABLE or IMMUTABLE (as appropriate).

Is there a way to grant default execute privileges on STABLE and IMMUTABLE functions to a role? Something similar to `alter default privileges in schema public grant select on tables to <role_name>;`

I'm using postgresql 9.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way.

You could probably write an event trigger to do it by examining the definition of the function in the catalogs.

Note that volatile functions can be read-only too, and stable functions can have side effects. So I don't think trying to do this based on volatility is correct anyway.